# Background Images in html style convert in next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
  <div className="readyContent" style="background-image: url(assets/images/banner/banner-new.png);">
   <div className="row w-100 align-items-center">
      <div className="col-md-7 dFlex-center">
         <div>
            <h2 style = "color:white">Hop on board!  <br />Let's Give Your <br /> Business a Personality  </h2>
           
         </div>
      </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

It does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js background-image css property cant load the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842419/next-js-background-image-css-property-cant-load-the-image)? If the `assets` folder is located in the `public` folder you should reference the image as `url(/assets/images/banner/banner-new.png)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite style like this and inform the results:

```
import bg from 'assets/images/banner/banner-new.png'

...

style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg.src})` }}
```